# udisks2: Use a specific mount point when mounting from file manager on-demand

Tags: debian, thunar, udisks

I have an internal partition that I do not automount using fstab, but mount on-demand from the file manager by clicking on the partition icon, using udisks2.
This setup works great, except that udisks2 creates the mount point automatically inside /media/username/, but the mount point that udisks2 creates uses the UUID of the partition as name, which is rather difficult when using the terminal, as the mount-point name alone is around 40 characters and the terminal prompt takes up more than half the width of the terminal, or more than that when you are deep inside the directory tree.
Is there a way to tell udisks2 to mount this specific partition to a mount-point that is already present in the location, when the partition is mounted on-demand, or force udisks2 to use a short name for the mount-point?
I'm using Debian 10 with Xfce and the file manager is Thunar. Udisks2 version 2.8.1

Comment: Put your partition's UUID in `/etc/fstab`, without the `auto` option. Read `man mount fstab`.

Comment: @waltinator That worked. So udisks read entries from fstab to mount partitions, if available. Could you make that an answer?